# Force file sync after file watcher runs

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I have a stylus file watcher that runs a custom script when a stylus file changes.  I'd like to have webstorm/idea re-sync all stylus files after the command completes, but the "output paths to refresh" seems inadequate to the task. That is, it's looking for me to specify a path/file when possibly all stylus files have been updated.

Is there a syntax or option that would cause webstorm to update all files or all files with a specific extension after running a file watcher?  If not, any other suggestions for triggering a re-sync (not manually) after executing a file watcher?

EDIT: WebStorm v9.0.3

Comment: try specifying the whole project dir ($ProjectFileDir$) as 'Output paths to refresh' value

Comment: @lena do you have some reason to believe this should work?  It doesn't work for me and it doesn't seem to match the function of the field (link a source and output file)

Comment: the project root folder is definitely updated. But seems it's not recursive - works for specified folder only and not for subfolders